# Why Mysql database table column get empty when using update function in Codeigniter Query builder

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, query-builder

Why a particular column gets updated with a null value? if I use

> $firstName = $this->input->post('first_name'); //this has a value.

It works finely if I assign string values(Hardcoded).

> $firstName = "First Name"

**Profile Update function in Controller**

```
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_auth')->id;
    $firstName = $this->input->post('first_name');
    $lastName = $this->input->post('last_name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    $data = array(
        'firstName' => $firstName,
        'lastName' => $lastName,
        'email' => $email,
    );

    $this->User_model->update_profile($user_id, $data);
```

**DB Update in Model**

```
    $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
    $this->db->update('user', $data);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

**Form View**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                      id="update_profile-form" class="update_profile-form"
                                      action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user/update_profile">
                                    <div class="modal-body">

                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                                                    <input style="padding: 5px;" type="text" class="form-input"
                                                           name="first_name"
                                                           id="first_name"
                                                           value=<?= $user->firstName ?>
                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                                                    <input style="padding: 5px;" type="text" class="form-input"
                                                           name="last_name"
                                                           id="last_name"
                                                           value="<?= $user->lastName ?>"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="last_name">Email</label>
                                                    <input style="padding: 5px;" type="text" class="form-input"
                                                           name="email"
                                                           id="email" placeholder="Email"
                                                           value="<?= $user->email ?>"/>
                                                    <span
                                                        class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <!--                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close-->
                                        <!--                                        </button>-->
                                        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the view where the form is displayed?

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Now check!

Comment: is it only the `first_name` that doesn't get updated? or are all fields?

Comment: @JavierLarroulet No, all the fields taking values from post method.

Comment: I know it's late: One question here is what format are the database columns which give the error (ideally Varchar). Please can you confirm what's the format?